# problems with computing normal for organized point cloud

Tags: c++, image-processing, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

Now I want using PCA method to compute normal for the organized point cloud transformed from the depth image.Here is what I do:

```
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> normObj;

normObj.setInputCloud (cloud);  //cloud is an organized point cloud  

pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree(new pcl::search::OrganizedNeighbor<pcl::PointXYZ>());  

normObj.setSearchMethod (tree);

//normObj.setRadiusSearch (0.05); 

normObj.setKSearch(10);   

PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals (new PointCloud<pcl::Normal>); 

normObj.compute (*normals);
```

the problem is when I run the program, there will be no result but without giving an error.What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Depending on how dense is your cloud, you might want to increase the value in |setKSearch| or |setRadiusSearch|.

Comment: Can you show us the error? It's the only way we can help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be too late but for people who are struggling this in the future, the structured point cloud normal can be estimated using
[IntegralImageNormalEstimation](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.html#normal-estimation-using-integral-images)
I am not sure the normal quality but it works for me.